# Compile Error: Class Batch_Class must implement the method: void Database.Batchable<SObject>.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List<SObject>)

Tags: apex, batch, compile-error

```
global class Batch_Class implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    public String Field;
    public String Query;
    public String Value;

    public Batch_Class (String f, String q, String v){

        Field = f;
        Query = q;
        Value = v;

    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){

           return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);

       }         
    global void excute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account>scope){

        for(Account a: scope){
            a.put(Field,Value);

        }
        update scope;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled "execute" as "excute":

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account>scope){
```